# Intellij doesn't add maven provided scoped dependencies to the classpath

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've got a project using Hadoop as a dependency with 'Provided' scope.  I'm unable to run the project in Intellij 13.1 without opening the module settings and changing the scope of all provided dependencies to Compile.  How can I get intellij do to this for me?

Comment: You should not be changing the poms just to run locally. `provided` means that the container to which you deploy your project's artifacts will have these modules in its classpath. You should configure your local container to operate in the same way. Alternatively, you could use a different profile for building a local dev version of your system, where the prod profile contains the `provided` dependencies, and the local profile contains the `compile` version of them.

Comment: Adding a maven profile with dependencies set to Compile and enabling it under 'Maven Projects' works. I don't understand what you mean by "container" though. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Have a look at solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453269/maven-provided-dependency-will-cause-noclassdeffounderror-in-intellij

Comment: @eaubin What he means by 'container' is that a library marked with the 'provided' scope is expected (as the name suggests) to be provided by the JDK or thet container (e.g. tomcat) at runtime.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is an option in run configuration:

**Include dependencies with "Provided" scope.**

[image]

Check it on. :)

Comment: super !! saved my day

Comment: What is the Gradle's alternative (for `complie-only` dependencies)?