# maven provided dependency will cause NoClassDefFoundError in intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

**IntelliJ** doesn't seem to put the provided dependency on the classpath when I run it, however I can do this successfully in **Eclipse**.
As it would be a lot more convenient for me, how can  I do this in **IntelliJ**?

Comment: show us your pom.xml and some output from "mvn compile", please

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same problem. Intellij does not include provided dependencies in classpath. See [this source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-54595). The best solution I found is to run it as maven app, using the `exec:java` goal. For example:

```
exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=com.splout.db.integration.NShardEnsemble -Dexec.args=4
```

Better solutions are welcome.

Comment: You can execute whatever you want in your ```test sources``` and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work in Maven via command line? The behaviour seems correct. Eclipse used to handle classpath badly, so I guess it still does.

There is a difference if you run something in [`Test source root` or `Source root`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html), since the scope **provided** is only available on the **compilation** and **test** classpath.

If you run a test, or a main method in  `Test source root`, then it can use provided dependencies, but if you try to execute something (via IntelliJ, or `exec-maven-plugin`) in `Source root`, then it will fail on ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ now has an option to `Include dependencies with provided scope` in the Run Configuration:

[image]

Any library marked as scope - `provided` means that the library (as the name suggests) is supposed to be provided by the JDK or the container (e.g. tomcat) at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

this answer is based on @Meo's answer.

`ALT + Enter` to create a unit test:

[image]

then run it :

[image]